# XML Validation Doesn't Validate One Attribute Based on Another Attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I have gone through many site and then created Xml Schema, where the other attributes are depends on the value of one the attributes.

The below xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Main>
  <Matter kind="fruits" calories="10" name="apple" quantity="10" color="red"/>
  <Matter kind="car" brand="ford" name="ikon" quantity="1" color="red"/>
  <Matter kind="country" continent="Asia" name="japan"/>
</Main>
```

The kind attribute can have fruits, car and country. And based on the attribute other parameter are needed, like for country value, the continent attribute required.

And the below is the XSD file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Main">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Matter"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Matter">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:alt cond="@kind='fruits'"> 
      <xs:attribute name="kind" use="required" type="xs:NCName" fixed="fruits"/>
      <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:alt>
      <xs:alt cond="@kind='car'"> 
      <xs:attribute name="kind" use="required" type="xs:NCName" fixed="car"/>
      <xs:attribute name="brand" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:NCName"/>
      </xs:alt>
      <xs:alt cond="@kind='country'"> 
      <xs:attribute name="kind" use="required" type="xs:NCName" fixed="country"/>
      <xs:attribute name="continent" type="xs:NCName" use="required"/>
      </xs:alt>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I am validating the XML file with the above XSD, I am getting the error that "Element alt is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Please help me to validate the above file, with proper XSD.

Comment: xs:alt is not a valid Xsd construct. Xsd does not validate based on the content of the document it only allows validating "shape". I think xs:alt might be an extension to schema and if this is the case you need to use a validator that understands how to process it. Out of the box your document is not a valid schema since it is using constructs (keywords) that are not defined in the XSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea of xsl:alt from. Perhaps some proprietary extension of XML Schema?

The XSD 1.1 standard has a facility called conditional type assignment that is a bit like this, with an element called xs:alternative. XSD 1.1 is supported in recent versions of Xerces and Saxon.

Comment: I think, the attribute condition check can not be achieved via XSD, got pointer to DSD http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/XML/schemas/dsd-example.html .

Comment: There are lots of validation technologies available. DSD is one I haven't encountered. If you aren't committed to the XSD route, the first place to look is Relax NG.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `xs:extension` as follows.
Here is a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main xmlns="http://www.example.com/matters">
    <Fruit calories="10" name="apple" quantity="10" color="red"/>
    <Car brand="ford" name="ikon" quantity="1" color="red"/>
    <Car brand="dodge" name="fire" quantity="1" color="blue"/>
    <Country continent="Asia" name="Japan"/>
    <Country continent="Europe" name="Italy"/>
</Main>
```

Here is the XSD for this XML. The only limitation is that elements of the same type should be grouped in sequence.
You can also add the fixed attributes, but since the name of the tag indicates the type, I didn't found them necessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/matters" xmlns="http://www.example.com/matters" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <!-- document structure -->
    <xs:element name="Main">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Fruit" type="fruitType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Car" type="carType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Country" type="countryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <!-- types definitions -->
    <xs:complexType name="matterType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="fruitType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="matterType">
                <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:NCName"/>
                <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:attribute name="calories" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="carType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="matterType">
                <xs:attribute name="brand" type="xs:NCName"/>
                <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:NCName"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="countryType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="matterType">
                <xs:attribute name="continent" type="xs:NCName" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create one type out of another. I think you should refactor and create new types with their own rules. Then you can continue with your original modified xsd and parse in one pass.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Main>
    <fruits calories="10" name="apple" quantity="10" color="red"/>
    <car brand="ford" name="ikon" quantity="1" color="red"/>
    <country continent="Asia" name="japan"/>
</Main>
```